# Is cookie writing limited based on the size of the cookie value?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following code which takes the value of a textarea and writes it to a cookie.

However, for large values it seems that the cookie does not get set.

```
var xVal = $('div#content-case div#edit-document textarea#feed-edit-box').val();
xVal = xVal.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 1);
var c_value = xVal + ((1 == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = "TempFile=" + c_value;
```

If so, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are limited to 4096 bytes in some browsers(IE), instead of save your values to a cookie use this http://www.jstorage.info/, the data will not be sent to the server every time you do a request and the storage size is much larger.

Comment: Can i need to pass the value to the server, is that possible?

Comment: It's not a good idea send a large amount of repeated data to your server every time you do a request, if this data will not change every time send it by ajax and save it in your session.